# How can I wrap text in parenthesis in only one key press in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a string in my IDE: `"No result"`. I want to wrap it in parentheses without having to put the cursor on the left, press (, go to the very right of the string and put a ) because sometimes the string is long
I can't do that with a keyboard press in visual studio code to have this
`("No result")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the text you want to wrap with parentheses and then press the opening bracket character. VS Code will wrap the text with opening and closing parentheses characters.

If the thing you want to wrap is within some kind of language-level delineated context, such as a string literal, you can put your cursor inside the string literal and use the `Expand Selection` command (or whatever keyboard shortcut it is bound to on your system) until what you want is selected. Not exactly one key press, but I don't see how you're going to get better.